# How to draw a Table on a canvas in python using Report Lab

Tags: python, reportlab

I have a table that i want to display on a canvas in python, i have displayed text in the canvas and i am returning the buffer to return a new FileResponse in another function.
My code :

```
     def Report(dict):
          from reportlab.lib.utils import ImageReader
          buffer = io.BytesIO()
          p = canvas.Canvas(buffer)
          textobject = p.beginText()
          textobject.setTextOrigin(200, 680)
          textobject.textLine('Title')
          p.drawText(textobject)
          logo = ImageReader('static/img/logo.png')
          p.drawImage(logo, 100, 700,width = 400,height=100,mask = None)
          data = [['00', '01', '02', '03', '04'],
        ['10', '11', '12', '13', '14'],
        ['20', '21', '22', '23', '24'],
        ['30', '31', '32', '33', '34']]
          f = Table(data)
          f.setStyle(TableStyle([('BACKGROUND', (1, 1), (-2, -2), 
          colors.green),
                       ('TEXTCOLOR', (0, 0), (1, -1), colors.red)]))

          p.showPage()
          p.save()

          buffer.seek(0)
          return buffer
```

Comment: Where is the input "dict" used in your function?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Table` inherits `Flowable`, in which has a method called `drawOn`.

```
width = 400
height = 100
x = 100
y = 800
f = Table(data)
f.wrapOn(p, width, height)
f.drawOn(p, x, y)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: And how to make it dynamic when it reaches end of pdf file to print on the next page?

Comment: It will be easier to use the doc templates for that purpose. E.g. `SimpleDocTemplate(buffer)`, then add the `Table` to the storyboard and build the document. 
`elements = []`
`elements.append(Table(data))`
`doc.build(elements)`

Comment: buffer = io.BytesIO()
    p = canvas.Canvas(buffer)
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate(p)
    elements = []

    elements.append(Table(data))
    doc.build(elements)


    p.showPage()
    p.save()

    buffer.seek(0)
    return buffer

Comment: Is it right to do that or their is any other method to do the table dynamic

Comment: You don't need `p.showPage()` and `p.save()` if you use `SimpleDocTemplate`. What did you get from buffer?

Comment: A side question - why does reportlab provide one way of adding elements to a buffer, and another way of using document templates and flowables? It seems somewhat trivial unless I'm misunderstanding something